# More elegant alternative to (*(uint16_t*)[[NSData] bytes])?

Tags: objective-c, pointers

I need to byte swap some bytes that represent an unsigned 16 bit integer.  The following code works, but seems a bit ridiculous:

```
CFSwapInt16(*(uint16_t*)[[myNSDataVariable] bytes]);
```

Here's what I've deduced is going on:

`[[myNSDataVariable] bytes]` returns a void pointer to a byte array.

The `(uint16_t*)` casts the void pointer to a `uint16_t` pointer.

The final outer `*` dereferences the `uint16_t` pointer, providing access to the actual `uint16_t` value.

Is there a more elegant way to get the `uint16_t` value from `NSData`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'd say the following is more readable:

```
uint16_t *valuePtr = (uint16_t *)[myNSDataVariable bytes];
uint16_t swappedValue = CFSwapInt16(*valuePtr);
```

But ultimately you're going to do this conversion somewhere. If you're doing it more than once, I'd recommend a function to make it clearer:

```
uint16_t SwappedIntegerFromData(NSData *data) {
    uint16_t *valuePtr = (uint16_t *)[data bytes];
    return CFSwapInt16(*valuePtr);
}

uint16_t value = SwappedIntegerFromData(myNSDataVariable);
```

But again, the conversions have to go *somewhere*.

Answer (score 3):

Not really.

You need the cast so that (Objective-)C knows that the pointer refers to a 2-byte value, you need the indirection to access those 2 bytes through the pointer.

If you really wanted to you could:

```
typedef uint16_t *UInt16Ptr;
```

and cast to `UInt16Ptr`, if losing one `*` makes it more elegant for you. You can also use dot notation treating `bytes` as a property. Combined this would give you:

```
CFSwapInt16(*(UInt16Ptr)myNSDataVariable.bytes);
```

But elegance is in the eye of the beholder, some will think that less elegant I'm sure.

Answer (score -2):

Here is something in C that is more elegant and "answers the mail":

```c
void  swap_bytes( uint16_t  *p_u )
{
    char  *p_b = (char *) p_u;

    char  saved = 0[ p_u ];
    0[ p_u ]    = 1[ p_u ];
    1[ p_u ]    = saved;
}
```

Do you think we could fit a UINTATHERIUM into a uint16_t?  Perhaps a neonate?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't see where that's more elegant

Comment: Yes, I agree.  I read the original spec, and it seemed to say much more than what it now says upon reading it.  Why would I bother calculating what's big-endian and such if all I have to do is put this byte here and that byte there?  I realized this and fixed it up forthwith.  My union, which I no longer need, was two bytes in size. But all it really had to be was a pair of bytes.  No unions of any size are necessary: I needed only two bytes.  But why?  Why bother determining whether the underlying CPU is big-endian?  I went back and reread the ORIGINAL question.